# Custom Container Not Full Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

please take a look at my sample code

HTML

```
   <div class="custom-container">
        <section class="parallax-bg-1 text-center" style="background-image:url('https://killtheboredomdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/skyline-of-rome.jpg?w=1920&h=768&crop=1')">
            <h1 class="">Welcome</h1>

            <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-container{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%,
}
section {
    height:350px;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.parallax-bg-1 {
    background: no-repeat top center fixed;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

containers

```
}
.custom-container{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%,
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1600px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1900px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1900px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1180px;
  }
}
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unpvuzaq/ (it works just fine in JS Fiddle but on my end it's not)

the picture is in parallax mode but take a look at my web screenshot it still has padding

image resolution 1920x1080

[image]

kindly help me.

Comment: Check parent div of custom-container.

Comment: Show more code to clarify the question.

Comment: what code do you need?

Comment: parent div of custom-container.
may be you add container class on parent div

Comment: i included all of my containers

Comment: add this in css  .container{ width:100%;padding: 0;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90495/discussion-between-atul-nagpal-and-nevi).

Comment: In your HTML what comes before <div class="custom-container"> ? That could be restricting the custom-container from being full width of the screen.

Comment: there is another class comes before the custom-container it's container-fluid but i tried removing it leaving custom-container alone but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add CSS outer div container,

```
.container.body-content{ 
   width: 100%; 
   padding: 0; 
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think image may smaller than your screen size...you should give image as stretch...

add style to section class:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: hello the image is 1920x1080 dimensions and i have tried adding background-size: cover; on section css it doesnt work

Comment: is there any parent div of custom-container div?

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom-container{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
section {
    height:350px;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.parallax-bg-1 {
    background: no-repeat top center fixed;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

background-size: 100%; is working on 4K resolution display. (tested)

Comment: you should clear cookies or something, because this should work.